# Netsuite AfterSubmit script creating customer

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

```
define ( ['N/record', 'N/ui/serverWidget', 'N/runtime','N/https'] ,// Add the callback function.function(record, serverWidget,runtime,https) {
```

```
    // In the afterSubmit function, begin creating a task record.
    function myAfterSubmit(context) {
        var tgType = context.type;
        if(tgType == 'create' || tgType == 'edit' || tgType == 'copy') {

        var saleOrder = context.newRecord;
        log.debug({title: 'Record Type ', details: context.newRecord.type });
        if (saleOrder.type == "salesorder" )
        {
            var uniqueKey = saleOrder.id
            log.debug("uniquekey",uniqueKey)  
        }
        else
        {
            log.debug("error",'No data found')
        }
    }
     
return {
    afterSubmit: myAfterSubmit
};
```

```
});
```

Hello Netsuite experts,

I am looking for solution to access created customer's info with aftersubmit function of userevernt script.

- salesorder is working well
- Tried "customer" and it's not triggering to the script.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do You want created customer's internal id in your script? if yes,
here is the code, in after submit for edit mode you need to use oldRecord
otherwise for newly created use newRecord(on create/copy mode and load the record). and deploy it on customer record as well.

```
function myAfterSubmit(context) {
        var tgType = context.type;
        if(tgType == 'create' || tgType == 'edit' || tgType == 'copy') {

        var rec= context.oldRecord;
        log.debug({title: 'Record Type ', details: context.oldRecord.type });
        if (rec.type == "customer" )
        {
            var customerIntId= rec.id
            log.debug("customerIntId",customerIntId)  
        }**strong text**
        else
        {
            log.debug("error",'No data found')
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Gayatri,
You are correct. I made the error of not deploying the script for the Customer record. It's fixed by adding a Customer record beneath the deployment section.

Comment: Hi @Mayur, If it was helpful to you. please vote up for my answer for that it could be relevant to others.